# Assign new data to an existing xarray.DataArray

Tags: python, variable-assignment, python-xarray

I have 20 netCDF files from WRF model (different runs) and I'm want to get *slp* variable from all these files and put into only one *xarray.DataArray*.

After reading the first file, I used **expand_dims** to add a new dimension. So, after that I tried to assign values obtained from the other files. However, I got the following error:

***ValueError: assignment destination is read-only***

Below is the code:

```py
arq = nc.Dataset( dataDir+lista[0] )
dados = wrf.getvar( arq, 'slp', wrf.ALL_TIMES )
arq.close()

pnmm = dados.expand_dims( dim={ 'membro':Narqs } )

for membro in np.arange(1,20):
    arq = nc.Dataset( dataDir+lista[ membro ] )
    dummy = wrf.getvar( arq, 'slp', wrf.ALL_TIMES )
    pnmm[ membro, :, :, :] = dummy
    del dummy
    arq.close()
```

here, *Narqs* is an integer variable with the number of netCDF files got from list *lista* which was obtained with **os.listdir()**.

After **expand_dims** I'm getting the desirable array shape with an extra dimension for all data from all files. However, the line

*pnmm[ membro, :, :, :] = dummy*

is producing the error. I tried to assign just the values of *dummy* (with *dummy.values*), but didn't work because *pnmm* is read-only.

So,

1) Why *pnmm* DataArray is read-only? Is it truly read-only or I'm accessing its elements in a wrong way?

2) Is there a way to easily assign values to *pnmm* DataArray?

I've tried using **xarray.concat** and it works, but I really would like to understand why the above approach didn't work, because it seems much more intuitive. Also, with **concat** I have to create and delete more *dummy* variables to make it works.

**UPDATE**:

As I have written above, using **xarray.concat** solves my problem and I show the code below:

```py
for membro in np.arange(0,20):
    if membro == 0:
        print( 'acessando arquivo 0' )
        arq = nc.Dataset( dataDir+lista[ membro ] )
        pnmm = wrf.getvar( arq, 'slp', wrf.ALL_TIMES )
        arq.close()
    else:
        print( 'acessando arquivo '+str( membro ) )
        arq = nc.Dataset( dataDir+lista[ membro ] )
        d2 = wrf.getvar( arq, 'slp', wrf.ALL_TIMES )
        arq.close()

        d3 = xr.concat( [pnmm,d2], dim='membro' )

        del pnmm, d2
        pnmm = d3.copy()
        del d3
```

However, even with this problem solved, I really would like to know how to do this in a simpler way, like using *pnmm[ membro, :, :, :] = dummy*. I also have tried other ways, like:

```py
dados = wrf.getvar( arq, 'slp', wrf.ALL_TIMES )                                                                                                                                                                        
pnmm = dados.copy(  deep=True, data=None )                                                                                                                                                                                        
pnmm = dados.expand_dims( dim={ 'membro':Narqs } )
```

However, the *read-only* problem still rises.

In other words: I just want to get the structure of a DataArray from a netCDF file, add a new dimension to this structure and assign values to this new object.

Thank you.

Mateus

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Why pnmm DataArray is read-only? Is it truly read-only or I'm accessing its elements in a wrong way?

It's ready only at this stage because it points directly to the netCDF file on disk.

> 2) Is there a way to easily assign values to pnmm DataArray?

My recommendation would be to use a more xarray-centric approach, avoiding the low-level netCDF4 library. You may be able to do exactly what you want in one line with [xarray.open_mfdataset](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html). Something like this:

```py
ds = xr.open_mfdataset('/path/to/files/*.nc', concat_dim='member')
```

If this fails, you may need to add a preprocessing function, or open the files individually and then manually call xarray.concat on the resulting datasets.

Comment: Hi, I already tried to read all files, but using <https://wrf-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html#dictionaries-of-wrf-file-sequences>. The big problem is that when getting **slp** from all files with **wrf.getvar** the memory is completely used and the PC slows down. With rainfall (RAINNC and RAINC) it works very well. Now, I've tried to make a deep copy from _dados_ to _pnmm_ and after using _expand_dims_ on _pnmm. However, I have same error: "ValueError: assignment destination is read-only".

Comment: Can you bypass `wrf` and just work directly with the netcdf files? Xarray should use lazy loading by default, and you shouldn't have to worry about these memory / copy / deep copy questions. I'm not sure what wrf-python is doing, but it sounds like it is not optimal.

What value does wrf-python add over just using xarray directly?

Comment: I think I can't bypass wrf-python. Wrf-python provides methods to extract variables from WRF model output, including variables derived from its output - post-processed variables. For example, your approach for open files with _open_mfdataset_ doesn't work: "ValueError: arguments without labels along dimension 'member' cannot be aligned because they have different dimension sizes: {2, 3, 5}".

Comment: Then it seems like a bug in wrf-python. Wrf-python needs to be refactored to take advantage of xarray's lazy loading. I recommend you open an issue at https://github.com/NCAR/wrf-python.

Comment: Yes, I believe so! I would do that. Thank you.